# Javamail : moving mail to spam / trash in yahoo

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I do a copy message from src folder ( inbox) to Trash / spam.

If i set the flag Flags.Flag.DELETED =true , the mail is getting purged  from the destination folder as  well ( ie it is moved from inbox but not seen in trash or spam )

If i do not set the flag, the mail will be there in both inbox as well as trash / spam.

After move , i close the folder.
I tried with close(true) as well as close(false) but no difference.

In gmail it works . I do not have Flags.Flag.DELETED set to true and the email is moved from inbox / trash .

Issue is coming for yahoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the DELETED flag **after** you copy the message?

Comment: flag is set before copying

Comment: it was a good clue. i changed the sequence. Copy . then close the src folder , then set the deleted flag and then close dest folder and it works.